# how to create pdf in react-native

Tags: react-native, pdf-generation

I want to create pdf in my app in react-native for word to pdf or html to pdf converter.I have tried all possible react-native packages but none of them give me a desired result what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the more specific answer to your problem :

```
import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';
    
    const createPdf = async () => {
     
      let h1 = "Hey Heading 1";
      let h2 = "heading 2";
      let para = "Something description";

      // use Backtick(`) to define html for your custom dynamic content 
      const pdf_html = `<div>
                          <h1>{h1}</h1>
                          <h1>{h2}</h1>
                          <h1>{para}</h1>
                        </div`;
    
        try {
            let options = {
              html: pdf_html,
              fileName: 'demofile',
              directory: 'Downloads',
              base64: true,
            };
            let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
            console.log(file);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nodeJS on the server? If you are, send the html to the server and use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to convert the html to a pdf.

Comment: could you please explain it a little bit more? if i request it using axios, how can i get the file in react-native? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you Checked [react-native-pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-lib).
It is pretty good module.
Otherwise consider server side rendering

Answer (score 0):

You can generate pdf file in react native with the npm package [react-native-html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-to-pdf).

Steps :

1. Create `HTML` template of your pdf file you want to generate.
2. Install the package and install pod in ios folder with `pod install`
3. Rebuild the app in android/ios.

```
import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';
    
 const createPdf = async () => {
    try {
        let options = {
          html: '<div>Hello pdf</div>',
          fileName: 'demofile',
          directory: 'Downloads',
          base64: true,
        };
        let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
        console.log(file);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```